# unwanted treeview node duplicating at the end of list

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have the following code but cant seem to find a reason (nor a solution) to why the parent node keeps appearing at the end of the list as a duplicate?

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\la")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    For Each dra In diar1

        'Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dra.FullName)
        If System.IO.Path.GetExtension(dra.Name).ToLower() = ".xls" Then
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Offerts")
            TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(dra.Name)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The code doesn't make any sense, you need to describe what you *expect* the tree to look like after it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first .xls file it finds, it creates an "Offerts" node in the root of the tree, and then creates a node with the filename under "Offerts".

On subsequent .xls files, it creates *another* "Offerts" node in the root, and then creates a node with the filename under the first node (the first "Offerts" node that was created).

So I think what you want to do is just create the "offerts" node once, at the root, so `TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Offerts")` should not be run each time it finds an .xls file.  So replacing that line with something like:

```
If TreeView1.Nodes.Count = 0 Then TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Offerts")
```

Will work, given the scenario.  If the treeview already has nodes, you'll have to modify that logic.

Comment: Thanks Tony thats makes sense now :)